# Syncing Exchange Inbox subfolders to Blackberry

Tags: exchange, outlook, blackberry, bes

I have a Blackberry user that has organized his Outlook such that he manually sorts mail messages into specific subfolders.

Example -

```
|--> Inbox 
|---->Mail from 2004 ( Subfolder of Inbox ) 
|--------> Business ( Subfolder of Mail from 2004 ) 
|--> Personal 
|--> Travel 
|--> Mail from 2003
```

When using the Blackberry this user is able to view the folder, however the folder is empty, despite knowing the folder has mail messages in it on the Exchange server. The handheld appears to sync without issue. The user receives new mail messages. I have Folder Redirection enabled and all folders checked marked. I am using BES 4.0.

So, I guess my questions is this - How are the Outlook subfolders sync'd with the Hnadheld? Additionally, if a mail message is on the handheld is moved into a subfolder from the handheld, will it be sync'd on the Exchange server?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Emails are not sync'd. They are forwarded to the BB and then as they get moved, deleted etc, the BB/BES will track what is done with them.  Hence only emails that have gotten forwarded can have this happen, there is no ability to browse the sub-folders. The remote search is the best option to find old email.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same setup.

As far as I can figure, there is no way to synchronize existing emails, whether in a subfolder or in the INBOX proper.  The BES will only deal with emails that it encounters after the syncing starts.

If you "File" an email into a different folder from the Blackberry, though, it definitely gets moved on the Exchange server.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, you can *not* sync existing emails to the device.

However, there is a trick to go and view the older mails using search. In the search menu, at the very top there is a word 'local'. Select this and you can choose remote. Make sure the service below is set to desktop and then browse to the folder you want.

It is slow but it works and has saved me before.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are partially correct.  The default BES config when the BB is activated is to sync the past 5 days or 200 messages in the inbox and sent folders only.  E.g. you have an Exchange server and a bunch of emails in your inbox, you activate a new BB, the BB will populate with the past 5 days (or 200 messages) of whatever is in your inbox/sent folder.

Subfolders will not sync existing email upon activation.  If you have folder redirection enabled for the subfolders, then any future emails in those subfolders will sync to the BB.  Messages moved to subfolders via the "filing" function on the BB will get moved on the Exchange server as well.

To my knowledge, there is no way to sync the subfolders so there's a complete copy of your mailbox on your BB.  The best option would be to enable folder redirection for future emails (as it sounds like you have), then use remote search as others have mentioned.  Remote search seems to work well...not as instant as having the messages locally, but it fills the need.